# How to import export modules return values to other js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to grasp the export import/export process and carrying over functions and their returns to another file. I came across this great example! But having trouble bringing that over into another file..

For example I get this error when running node testing.js . Which I thought you could pass your parameters over.

**ERROR Output**

```
console.log(testClass.authy)(app);
                             ^

ReferenceError: app is not defined
```

**helper.js**

```
module.exports.auth = function (app) {
    console.log("return authy")
    var app = "1";
    return app;
};
```

**testing.js**

```
const testClass = require('../commands/helper.js');
console.log(testClass.auth)(app);
```

Comment: `console.log(testClass.authy)(req, res);` will always error, even if you define the missing vars. `console.log` returns `undefined`, which you are trying to call as a function. `testClass.authy` is a typo? You tagged it with es6-modules, but are using commonJS syntax. You tagged it ecmascript-6, but there's no ES6 specific code. This is so riddled with errors and inconsistencies it's hard to tell what your actual question is.

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith  this was a terrible mistake on my part. Basically I would like app = 1 to carry over to testing.js

Comment: Much, much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when logging the result of a function to the console, you should use `console.log(function())`, not `console.log(function)()`.

Second of all, you are passing '`app`' in as an argument, which is a value you give to the function, and then redefining it straight away. Your function doesn't need any arguments, it should just be `function() { ... }`, and then be called as `testClass.auth()`. Right now, you are trying to pass a variable '`app`' into your function, which you haven't defined yet.

So in the end, your code should be:

**helper.js**

```
module.exports.auth = function () {
  console.log("return authy")
  var app = "1";
  return app;
};
```

**testing.js**

```
const testClass = require('../commands/helper.js');
console.log(testClass.auth());
```

The value of '`app`' is returned to the `console.log` function, which then displays it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. that tells me a lot about basic functionality i just can't seem to gras for dumb reasons!!